# Add hyperlinks to linked images

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I'm trying to add hyperlinks to images, which were added via `IncludePicture` fields.

For example, this is an image:

```
{ IncludePicture "C:\\Test\\Image 1.png" \d }
```

And so, it should be added hyperlink to it:

```
C:\\Test\\Image 1.png
```

After that, I can click on my image in document with mouse, and it will be opened in file manager.

Here is the code. For some reason, it doesn't properly work. How it should be fixed?

```
Sub AddHyperlinksToImages()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim iShp As InlineShape
    For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        iShp.Hyperlink.Address = iShp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName 'Doesn't work

        'Just for testing
        'fullPath = iShp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        'MsgBox fullPath
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Sub AddHyperlinksToImages()
    ' 22 Sep 2017

    Dim Fld As Field
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Tmp As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        With Fld
            If InStr(1, Trim(.Code), "includepicture", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                If .InlineShape.Hyperlink Is Nothing Then
                    i = InStr(.Code, Chr(34))
                    If i Then
                        FilePath = Replace(Mid(.Code, i + 1), "\\", "\")
                        i = InStr(FilePath, "\*")
                        If i Then FilePath = Left(FilePath, i - 1)
                        Do While Len(FilePath) > 1
                            i = Asc(Right(FilePath, 1))
                            FilePath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - 1)
                            If i = 34 Then Exit Do
                        Loop
                        If i > 1 Then ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add .InlineShape, FilePath
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Fld
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, partially. Currently I'm trying to fix it someway. There are several problems: 1) If I just open a document and launch the macro, it will give me an error. To avoid this error, images must be updated, i.e. first open a document, then press Ctrl-A, and then F9, and then launch the macro. This way, the script will be launched without an error. 2) Hyperlinks are a bit broken, because 2.1) Some letters are trimmed if path contains spaces, 2.2) For some reason, \\ in path become \\\\. [Here is the image showing it](https://i.imgur.com/aLVllJy.png).

Comment: As I understand, the problem with spaces could be fixed using `FilePath = Split(Trim(Replace(.Code, " ", "%20")))(1)`. But it doesn't work. It's a bit weird, because something like `FilePath = Split(Trim(Replace(.Code, "img ", "img%20")))(1)` works fine.

Comment: One. You might add code to update the fields. I think it is something like `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` and might be added at the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: Two. My code simply copies the path found in the field and uses it in creating the hyperlink. `Replace(.Code, "  ", " ")` is targeted at the double spacing Word inserts before and after the path name. If there might be double spaces in the file name itself another method might be necessary. `%20` is not useful unless it is contained in the extracted file path in which case you need not know about it. Find out if the path is corrupted before it is assigned to the hyperlink.

Comment: I made some improvements to the code. Please take a look.

Comment: It works) I slightly changed it, to make possible custom path for full-sized images. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/raw/PN67PCU3. Is it good enough from your point of view?

Comment: "From my point of view" it's beautiful! Perfect code-writing. The one fly in the ointment I found (after much scrutiny!) is the `Exit Sub`in the middle of the procedure. I would have used `If Len(CustomPath) Then` and placed the `End If` at the end of the procedure. Perhaps it's more a question of personal preference :-)